# How to remove outer quotes from square bracket in array value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this array and I need to use it in Charts

in **data index** I have this value **[1,9]** and it's coming form the comma split explode function without any quotes around it.

```
$main_arr = array(
        "label" => 'Total Clicks', 
        "data" => [$total_clicks], 
        "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)", 
    );
```

Then I use json_encode to turn the array into json format,

```
[{"label":"Total Clicks","data":["1, 9"],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"}]
```

As you can see above there are double quotes in the square bracket, if I pass static value in the data index i.e [1, 9] it works fine. I tried regex, substring, rtrim etc but didn't work anyone.
Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `explode` and probably `trim` and cast to `int`.

Comment: @u_mulder tried int but then it only returns first int value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems at once here. First of all your values are strings, and secondly you have an multiple values that you want to explode so you have singular values:

```php
$total_clicks = '1, 9'; // value guessed based on unexpected output in question

$clickArray = explode(',', $total_clicks);
$clickArray = array_map('trim', $clickArray); // remove white spaces
$clickArray = array_map('intval', $clickArray); // cast everything to int
$main_arr = array(
    "label" => 'Total Clicks',
    "data" => $clickArray,
    "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
);

echo json_encode($main_arr);
```

this outputs:

```
{"label":"Total Clicks","data":[1,9],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"}
```

For a more sloppy approach you could even skip the line where I trim the whitespaces away, as casting to integer will do this implicitly, however I like to have a clean flow of handled data.

Answer (score 1):

Converting string to array of `ints`:

```
$total_clicks = "1, 9";
print_r(array_map('intval', explode(', ', $total_clicks)));
```

Converting string to array of `strings`:

```
$total_clicks = "1, 9";
print_r(array_map('trim', explode(', ', $total_clicks)));
```